# Exporting data using sketch tool in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, export, csv, polygon-creation, arcgis-custom-widget

I am looking to see if it possible to extract data from a feature when we use sketch tool. After I draw a polygon it is selected as a feature what can I write to get the data behind that select feature may be in a grid to show what I have selected and have capability to export to csv.

I tried using "highlight features by geometry" but that only gives polygon and I need other shapes and also need to have multiple features created at a time which was not happening

```
const sketch = new Sketch({ layer: layer, view: view }); view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right")
```

Comment: Where is the data you're trying to get? If I'm reading this correctly, you want to draw a polygon on the map (with the sketch tool), and then use that polygon to query....another layer? What is that other layer?

Answer (score 1):

We need you to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve before we can help any further, but what I can understand from your post is that you are trying to get features from a layer behind a certain geometry you draw.

Esri already provides an example for that:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-scenelayerview-query-stats/index.html

I think you can use that as a base for what you need to do to get the features from a geometry, and If you have any more questions regarding how to extract the data or you get stuck in your own implementation of that example you can open another question.